# How laravel facade can use DB and DB instance at the same time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade

I use DB facade. I see it can use in DB::connection from Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager and DB::select from Illuminate\Database\Connection.

[image]

I don't understand how one facade can apply two serivce?

Thank you for your asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Facade can point to multiple classes for different methods. This is possible through the magic method [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

Here's the `__call` method of the `DatabaseManager` class:

```
 /**
 * Dynamically pass methods to the default connection.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    return $this->connection()->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

The `DB` facade points to the `DatabaseManager` class and if the method is not found the `DatabaseManager` then forwards the call to the `Connection` class.